# Getting #N/A for any calculations that reference a cell by name

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel file that consists of 8 Worksheets.

Throughout the Excel file, there are calculations that take place in various cells that reference other cells in other worksheet and refer to them by name only.

For example in Worksheet 2, I have a cell D12 and the formula in this cell is `=CostIssue`. *CostIssue* is a cell in Worksheet 1.

Using **PHPExcel** I managed to read the Excel file, manipulate some cells and then generate an HTML of it, but as I mentioned, in all the cells that reference named cells I am getting *#N/A*.

Any way to solve this or must I manually edit the entire file to reference these named cells in another way (i.e. by worksheet and cell number)?

Thanks

Update:

Some more info. Sheet 2, cell D12 contains `=CostIssue`
*CostIssue* is the name of cell C37 in Sheet 1 which contains: `=VLOOKUP($C$9,$Params.$B$6:$D$10,2,0)`

Comment: Assuming that these are "named ranges", PHPExcel should be perfectly capable of reading them and using them in formula calculations... have you tried debugging using [this method](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357) to see how PHPExcel is trying to access these named references?

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. I am not sure if this I did this correctly, but I pointed the debugging script to Sheet 2 cell D12 which contains `=CostIssue` and this is the result: **Formula Value is40 Expected Value is UNKNOWN Parser Stack :- Array ( ) Calculated Value is 40 Evaluation Log: Array ( )**

Comment: I added some more info the original question in case it helps.

Comment: That sounds like the cell referenced by the name `CostIssue` has a value of (or a formula that returns) 40, which should be what you're getting returned by a call to `getCalculatedValue()` for cell D12

Comment: But it is appearing as #N/A in PHPExcel.

Comment: Your comment from the debug `Calculated Value is 40` is confusing me.... can you identify a small subset of spreadsheet that demonstrates the problem that can be uploaded, because I can't really understand the contradictions here.... `getCalculatedValue()` isn't returning `#N/A!` in that case, it's returning `40`

Comment: Apologies, I did not explain properly. When I output the relevant sheet as HTML, the contents of the respective cell say "#N/A". I will try to see if I can share part of this spreadsheet.

Comment: Apologies, I had applied the debug script to the wrong sheet and cell. Now that I understand how the active sheet works I have applied it to the correct sheet and cell and this is what I get: `Formula Value is =CostIssue Expected Value is 0.5 Parser Stack :- Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Value [value] => CostIssue [reference] => ) ) Calculated Value is #N/A` - is this helpful at all or do you still need access to the Excel sheet?

Comment: Well, as PHPExcel should normally handle named references without problem, and in this case it's failing to identify the cell that is being referenced, then it would still be useful

Comment: Is there any way I can send you a sample privately? It's not for public consumption I am afraid.

Comment: Received, will take a look tonight

Comment: @MarkBaker were you able to look at this all? I would love to be able to use PHPExcel for this project. If you think the issue is related to the Excel file I would be happy see if we can amend the file to make it work with PHPExcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking at this, using the Calc Engine debugging function, and am still unclear about the actual problem.

Using cell `D12` on worksheet `Executive Summary` which contains the formula `=Input!C37`, and cell `C37` on the `Input` worksheet contains the formula `=VLOOKUP($C$9,Params!$B$6:$D$10,2,FALSE)` which evaluates to `0.5` (formatted as a percentage in the cells).

With the debug code

```
function testFormula($sheet, $cell) {
    $formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    echo 'Formula Value is ' , $formulaValue , PHP_EOL;
    $expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    echo 'Expected Value is '  , ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? $expectedValue : 'UNKNOWN') , PHP_EOL;


    $calculate = false;
    try {
        $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
            ->parseFormula($formulaValue, $sheet->getCell($cell));
        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        $calculate = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($calculate) {
        try {
            $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
            echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
                ->getDebugLog()->getLog());
            echo PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($sheet->getParent())
                ->getDebugLog()->getLog());
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}


$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Executive Summary');
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)
    ->getDebugLog()->setWriteDebugLog(true);

testFormula($sheet,'D12');
```

I get the results

```
Formula Value is =Input!C37
Expected Value is 0.5
Parser Stack :-
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Cell Reference
            [value] => Input!C37
            [reference] => Input!C37
        )

)

Calculated Value is 0.5
Evaluation Log:
Array
(
    [0] => Testing cache value for cell Executive Summary!D12
    [1] => Executive Summary!D12 => Evaluating Cell C37 in worksheet Input
    [2] => Executive Summary!D12 => Testing cache value for cell Input!C37
    [3] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating Cell C9 in current worksheet
    [4] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluation Result for cell Input!C9 is a string with a value of "both cost and speed-to-market"
    [5] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating Cell B6 in worksheet Params
    [6] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!B6 in worksheet Params is a string with a value of "only cost (speed-to-market remains unchanged)"
    [7] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating Cell D10 in worksheet Params
    [8] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D10
    [9] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluating Cell A10 in current worksheet
    [10] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A10 is a floating point number with a value of 5
    [11] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluating 5 - 1
    [12] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [13] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluating Cell A10 in current worksheet
    [14] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A10 is a floating point number with a value of 5
    [15] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluating 5 - 1
    [16] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [17] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluating 4 / 4
    [18] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!D10 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 1
    [19] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D10 in worksheet Params is a floating point number with a value of 1
    [20] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating Range "Params!B6" : "Params!D10"
    [21] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!C6
    [22] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C6 => Evaluating Cell D6 in current worksheet
    [23] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C6 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D6 is a floating point number with a value of 0
    [24] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C6 => Evaluating 1 - 0
    [25] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C6 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 1
    [26] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!C7
    [27] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 => Evaluating Cell D7 in current worksheet
    [28] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D7
    [29] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluating Cell A7 in current worksheet
    [30] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A7 is a floating point number with a value of 2
    [31] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluating 2 - 1
    [32] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 1
    [33] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluating Cell A10 in current worksheet
    [34] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A10 is a floating point number with a value of 5
    [35] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluating 5 - 1
    [36] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [37] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluating 1 / 4
    [38] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 -> Params!D7 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.25
    [39] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D7 is a floating point number with a value of 0.25
    [40] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 => Evaluating 1 - 0.25
    [41] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C7 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.75
    [42] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!C8
    [43] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 => Evaluating Cell D8 in current worksheet
    [44] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D8
    [45] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluating Cell A8 in current worksheet
    [46] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A8 is a floating point number with a value of 3
    [47] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluating 3 - 1
    [48] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 2
    [49] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluating Cell A10 in current worksheet
    [50] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A10 is a floating point number with a value of 5
    [51] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluating 5 - 1
    [52] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [53] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluating 2 / 4
    [54] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 -> Params!D8 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.5
    [55] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D8 is a floating point number with a value of 0.5
    [56] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 => Evaluating 1 - 0.5
    [57] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C8 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.5
    [58] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!C9
    [59] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 => Evaluating Cell D9 in current worksheet
    [60] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D9
    [61] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluating Cell A9 in current worksheet
    [62] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A9 is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [63] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluating 4 - 1
    [64] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 3
    [65] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluating Cell A10 in current worksheet
    [66] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!A10 is a floating point number with a value of 5
    [67] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluating 5 - 1
    [68] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 4
    [69] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluating 3 / 4
    [70] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 -> Params!D9 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.75
    [71] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D9 is a floating point number with a value of 0.75
    [72] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 => Evaluating 1 - 0.75
    [73] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C9 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0.25
    [74] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!C10
    [75] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Evaluating Cell D10 in current worksheet
    [76] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D10
    [77] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Retrieving value for cell Params!D10 from cache
    [78] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Evaluation Result for cell Params!D10 is a floating point number with a value of 1
    [79] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Evaluating 1 - 1
    [80] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 -> Params!C10 => Evaluation Result is a floating point number with a value of 0
    [81] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D7
    [82] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Retrieving value for cell Params!D7 from cache
    [83] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D8
    [84] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Retrieving value for cell Params!D8 from cache
    [85] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D9
    [86] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Retrieving value for cell Params!D9 from cache
    [87] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Testing cache value for cell Params!D10
    [88] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Retrieving value for cell Params!D10 from cache
    [89] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating Function VLOOKUP() with 4 arguments
    [90] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluating VLOOKUP( "both cost and speed-to-market", { "only cost (speed-to-market remains unchanged)", 1, 0; "mainly cost", 0.75, 0.25; "both cost and speed-to-market", 0.5, 0.5; "mainly speed-to-market", 0.25, 0.75; "only speed-to-market", 0, 1 }, 2, FALSE )
    [91] => Executive Summary!D12 -> Input!C37 => Evaluation Result for VLOOKUP() function call is a floating point number with a value of 0.5
    [92] => Executive Summary!D12 => Evaluation Result for cell Input!C37 in worksheet Input is a floating point number with a value of 0.5
)
```

which is exactly what I would expect to see, with a correct result

Similarly, if I use the `toArray()` method, I'm getting `50%` displayed in cell [12]['C']

**EDIT**

Can you ensure that you're running the latest develop branch code for PHPExcel, because there have been a couple of fixes to the `VLOOKUP()` function since the last production release

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look into this. If I use your latest develop branch then it works perfectly. Whereas in the stable 1.8 version it is returning #N/A. How stable is the develop currently, can we use it in a production environment at all?

Comment: Develop is pretty stable code, close to release quality, and approaching the point where I shall be doing a new tagged release

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your time and effort. Really appreciate it.